R - Why is bgtest showing no autocorrelation when order is set to a higher number, but shows autocorrelation at order = 1
Upon reading, I saw that bgtest (Breusch-Godfrey test, from lmtest pkg) can diagnose autocorrelation of higher orders than just 1, which is the maximum order the dwtest (Durbin-Watson test, from lmtest) can diagnose. So I decided to use bgtest for my model diagnostics.
When I set order=10 for my bgtest, it showed that I cannot reject the null of no autocorrelation at the 5% level but when I set order=1, the p-value becomes smaller, leading me to conclude that there is autocorrelation higher than 1.
Shouldn't bgtest capture any correlation at any order up to 10 lags?
Attached is the console output in R Studio.
> bgtest(ES_CoalCO2,order = 10)

Breusch-Godfrey test for serial correlation of order up to 10

data:  ES_CoalCO2
LM test = 18.223, df = 10, p-value = 0.05131

but when I use order = 1:
> bgtest(ES_CoalCO2,order = 1)

Breusch-Godfrey test for serial correlation of order up to 1

data:  ES_CoalCO2
LM test = 8.934, df = 1, p-value = 0.002799


Are you familiar with the need to adjust p-values when testing multiple hypotheses?  If not, that would be a good place to start.
